# MySQL/phpMyAdmin - Only root user can log in

Tags: mysql

I've been having some issues trying to log in as non-root users from a .php file onto phpMyAdmin.

I've set up a login form that uses the root user to check if the login that someone uses matches an entry in the mysql.User table and then stores the username and password as session variables which I'm using to try and log in to MySQL and perform user specific tasks later.

This is the code I'm having issues with:

```
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = $_SESSION['myusername']; // Mysql username 
$password = $_SESSION['mypassword']; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "gcim"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "permissions"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

myusername and mypassword are just the session variables I've stored and they're set to the values exactly how they should be, "gcim" is the database I'm trying to access and "permissions" is the table

Trying to execute the code results in the following:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'BUT03'@'localhost' (using       password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcim\permissions\permissions.php on line 12
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'BUT03'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue isn't a wrong hostname, username or password because even if I change the connection line to:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "BUT03", "test", "gcim");
```

it still gives me the same error

Here's the setup of my mysql.User table:
http://puu.sh/dDxd3/5e25f315f4.png

Anyway, any help would be very much appreciated, 
Thanks

EDIT: I've been experimenting and I've come to the conclusion that the ONLY way to get a successful login to MySQL is using the root account with no password, any attempt to log in with a password will give me the same error, as well as removing the password from a non-root account and trying to log in with no password which gives me the following error: Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'gcim'

I have a feeling that there's some issue with the server settings, was I meant to change anything from the default phpMyAdmin settings?

EDIT: I just tried to log in to phpMyAdmin itself as 'BUT03'@'localhost' and I appear to have no privileges at all even though everywhere I can see I've granted all possible privileges to that account, could this be affecting anything and does anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: I'm confused by "I'm pretty sure that the issue isn't a wrong hostname, username or password because even if I change the connection line to..." where you show a different way to attempt connecting, but that also fails -- which certainly makes me think that you DO have a password/username/hostname problem.

Comment: the account might exist, but did you `grant` access to the `gcim` db for that account? a user in mysql can exist without ANY db-access permissions at all

Answer (score 0):

I assume passowrds are saved not in plain text, but hashed. That would mean your *hashed* password is 'test', and you actual password is something unknown. Change your password to test with this function

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'BUT03'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('test');
```

see: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: Little confused, I understand the plain text and hashing but where am I supposed to run the function? If I try run it in the SQL section on phpMyAdmin I get the error #1133 - Can't find any matching row in the user table

Comment: @Nanne why you assumed password as 'test' ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu Probably because he looked at the picture where I had my password for the account BUT03 set to 'test' temporarily for testing

Comment: If you go to the Users tab, phpMyAdmin guides you through creating a user and properly hashes the password. How did you create these users in the first place?